# OLEDB query on Excel without headers: How do I specify Columns?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to be able to handle Excel files versions 97 - 2010 and also those with and without header info.

Don't need help with connection strings : that works.

What I do need help with is querying worksheets that do not have header information i.e. no descriptor of a column's data in the first row. How do I refer to these columns in the OLEDB query?
I've tried the following

```
"Select [Sheet2$A] from [Sheet2$]"  //selecting Column A
"Select [Sheet2$A$] from [Sheet2$]"  //selecting Column A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the columns as F1, F2, ... Fn, numbering from the first selected column.

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$G5:Z12]
```

g5 = row 1, column F1.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$G5:Z12]
WHERE F2 = 'abc' AND F3 > #2011/01/31#
```

Answer (score 0):

This post put me onto the answer, Thanks!
Just a minor clarification that kept me guessing for a while: In the above 
    SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$G4:Z12]
note that it is the sheet name not the number that goes into the part "Sheet1" E.g. "Changes", the $ that follows it vital and then no other $'s as might be used for excel ranges. In my case the full string reads:
    SELECT * from [Changes$A3:Z13]