# Uploading excel file to DataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am currently making a program on uploading excel file to datagridview. I am thinking of making it flexible and more user friendly. My question is, is it possible to set what row or what column to start the upload of the excel file? 
Because what I am doing right now is uploading all content of the excel file.

This is my code :

```
string path = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\";";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(path);

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

(textbox2.text is for the Sheet Name of the Excel File)

Comment: I know you can set which cell you want to specifically be in with : `DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex]`

Comment: thanks for your answer but how can i put it on my code? please help me..

Comment: @WhyCry, I think your cell references are for the DataGrid, not for the Data Source.

Comment: I misread the question I think. Not sure what was going through my head when I was looking at his code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use range in your select query.
For example if you want to upload only specific content you can use the following query

```
"Select * from [" + textBox2.Text + "$[A1:C100]"
```

Where A1 and C100 are start and end cell numbers. You can dynamically construct the query based on required range.

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that from the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values of the cells as part of the query.  For example, to query the range B1 to F4:

`"Select * from Sheet1$[B1:F4]"`

You can also refer to the columns using F1, F2, F3, etc.  Refer to this answer for reference:

[OLEDB query on Excel without headers: How do I specify Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248212/oledb-query-on-excel-without-headers-how-do-i-specify-columns)