# oledb query-condition with column by number

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am reading a excel-document via oledb. When there is no headerrow, how do i use the columns in my query to set up conditions?

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [MY_SHEET$A3:M] WHERE [1] IS NOT NULL;
```

When i try this, i get the following error:

> No value was specified for at least one required parameter.

I want to use the column-number for my condition. When i say `HDR=TRUE` in my connectionstring, i could use the column-name, but there are some duplicate-names in the document which leads to the problem, that i get the value of the wrong column. Renaming the columns in the document would be a solution, but is this possible with using the columnnumbers?

---

According the comments of Steve and Simo i tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [MY_SHEET$A3:M] WHERE [F1] IS NOT NULL;
```

But i get the same error-message. I tried it with `HDR=TRUE` and `HDR=FALSE` WIth `[]` arround `F1` and wihtout.

---

Here i uploaded the xlsx-file: https://ufile.io/fky0l
The exact command-text is `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A3:M] WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL`
Here is the connectionstring

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=D:\stack.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel
>   12.0 Xml;HDR=TRUE\""

Here is the codesnippet:

```
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\stack.xlsx;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=TRUE\"";

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A3:M] WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL";
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            var value = reader.Get<string>(0);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use F1, F2, F3.... as column names

Comment: using oledb, you can copy everything from the excel into a data table and than work on it using rows and columns. I'm used to this approach.

Comment: I get the same error-message using [F1]. I have tried with HDR=FALSE and HDR=TRUE.

Comment: @Simo I try to avoid creating a datatable. I only use the current row of a datareader. Is this possible wihtout creating and populating a datatable?

Comment: Refer to the column as 'F1' for column 1, 'F2' for column 2, ecc...

Here you can see better what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248212/oledb-query-on-excel-without-headers-how-do-i-specify-columns

Comment: I tried it, but still the same error.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce that problem. Probably it is something related to your Excel file. Which connectionstring are you using? Can you upload the excel where we can use it for tests?

Comment: Also that error is produced also when something cannot be used as column name or **table** name. Are you sure about the name of your sheet?

Comment: I uploaded the xls-file. i updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm was my connectionstring. The possible values for HDR are YES and NO. I was using TRUE and FALSE. After changing my connectionstring to:

> "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\stack.xlsx;Extended
>   Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\""

Everything worked...